# Write a c++ function that will prompt a user for an integer and convert it to binary and print in reverse order

Tags: c++, binary, integer, reverse, prompt

Here is my code, and my error message is, "error C4716: 'decToBinary': must return a value"
Basically, I want the user to input an integer and have the program return the binary expansion in reverse order. How do I go about fixing this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: you can use `std::bitset`

Comment: When you don't want to return a value from your function, use `void`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/#void

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear: you declared that your function would return an `int`, but you never did.

Comment: And it was declared to return a single `int` not an array of 32 integers.

Comment: @drescherjm how does one declare a function that returns an array of 32 integers?

Comment: At present, your function isn't returning *anything*.

Comment: Maybe `std::array<int,32>` although a `std::string` probably is a better choice if you can't use `std::bitset` instead of this.